# Div get white background when hover over it (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, background, hover

I used a slide function in Jquery.
When i'm hovering over the div it got a white background color.
It doesn't matter if it's a PNG image or a self made shape in CSS.

How do i get rid of this? It happens in all browsers and i have seen this problem in other forums, but without a right answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/7yHR9/

Comment: Do you also have some code to share with us?

Comment: Could you assemble a fiddle so that we could see it happening?

Comment: What browser? Where's the code to reproduce the issue? Possibly links of the forums you've been to and what you've tried? Make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to reproduce the problem preferably.

Comment: I never made a jsfiddle before, so i hope this one is right: http://jsfiddle.net/7yHR9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it *is* transparent - it's just not doing what you think it's doing.

I've slowed down your animation, added a background colour to the container div, and put a border around the default div; you'll see what you're doing is squishing the upper div, not sliding the rounded corner on top of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/7yHR9/17/

Note that you can see the pink through the rounded corner (ie the rounded corners *are* transparent)

Comment: You're right! Thank you so much, I struggled with this issue a long time.